# creating button with icon in HTML action link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to put some icons or make a button on HTML action link, because currently I just have a plain text with hyperlink:

here is my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
                            "Remove",
                            "Delete",
                            new { id = item.name},
                            new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove "+ @item.name +" to list ?');" })
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try Bootstrap glyphicon CSS styles by using `@class = glyphicon` and mention icon to insert in `htmlAttributes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add icons to `ActionLink` helper using Bootstrap CSS selectors. Since the action purpose is to delete data, your button should have CSS selector [`glyphicon-trash`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/) associated with the link:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Delete", new { id = item.name },
                  new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash", 
                  onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove "+ @item.name +" to list ?');" })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use class for your icon like this

```
  @Html.ActionLink("action", "controller", new { id = yourid }, new { @title = "Edit", @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Remove","Delete", new { id = item.name}, new { @class = "glyphicon glyphicon-search", @tabindex = "20" }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove "+ @item.name +" to list ?');" })
```

Comment: Can you add some explanations?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply a CSS class to the htmlAttributes object.

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Button Name", "Index", null, new { @class="classname" }) %>
```

and then create a class in your stylesheet

```
a.classname
{
    background: url(../Images/image.gif) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 150px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```